# The Parameter Doesn't Retrieve the Value of Uploaded File

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

Goal:
I would like to have the second input name "file2" to be uploaded automatically to the actionresult with support of the jquery code.

Problem:
It doesn't work because HttpPostedFileBase file2 is null. it is supposed to be contain any value based on uploaded file with support of jquery.

Info:
There is a purpose why I'm asking about this unusual approach.

Thank you!

```
public ActionResult UploadShipments(HttpPostedFileBase file, HttpPostedFileBase file2)
{


---
}
```

---

```
<input name="file" type="file" accept=".xml, .txt" />

<input name="file2" type="file" accept=".xml, .txt" hidden />
```

---

```
$("#file1id").change(function (){
  if($('#file2id').length){
     $('#file2id').remove();
  }
  $(this).clone().attr('id', 'file2id').attr('type', 'hidden').insertAfter($(this));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ayd4x079/

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add `name` attribute too:

```
$(this).clone()
       .attr({'id'   : 'file2id',
              'type' : 'hidden',
              'name' : 'file2'})
       .insertAfter($(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

input `type` should be `file` and you have to add `name` attribute like following. Hope this will help you.

```
$(this).clone().attr({'id' : 'file2id', 'type' : 'file', 'name' : 'file2'})
               .insertAfter($(this)).hide();
```